# C outputs 1 when I key in a string into an int array, how to error handle a non int input?

Tags: c, string, integer, return, scanf

This piece of code takes in a 7 digit number by a user and returns the same number backwards. However when I enter in a string e.g. "qwerty" it returns me a 1. How do I prevent this from happening and to ensure it works only if user enters a valid 7 digit int?

I have tried using if statements to check the input however it still returns a 1 when I enter a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    int arr[7];
    printf("Enter a 1-7 digit number: ");
    scanf("%7d", &num);

    while(num){
        for(int i = 6; i >= 0; i--){
            arr[i] = num%10;
            num /= 10;
            if(arr[i]){
                printf("%d", arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the result of scanf function in order to achieve that, see example below.

```c
    [...]
    printf("Enter a 1-7 digit number: ");

    int converted = scanf("%7d", &num);
    if (converted != 1)
    {
        puts("Input error!");
        return -1;
    }
    [...]
```

For further information, see [scanf man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html),

> On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Comment: A few things to notice, this answers how to prevent the user from entering "qwerty", as your question states, but keep in mind that it will read up to the 7 numeric characters specified by your format string and ignore everything else, so if you enter "1234567890", it will consider only "1234567". In time, the remainder of the contents won't be discarded.